# SQL Server - Data deletion issue

Tags: sql, sql-server

I currently got 2 DEV SQL Servers which is used by 4 Developers for their day to day work.

Yesterday, data out of few tables on DEV instance got deleted

Now I'm struggling how to track back who had deleted the data as everybody is saying they haven't deleted the data. Only failed login auditing was enabled on SQL Server

How can we track back - who deleted the data on that SQL SERVER?

Is there any way moving forward, I can keep track of DELETE/DROP statement which someone is executing on SQL SERVER

Regards

Comment: ('Dev' servers are places where developers should be allowed to delete data, whether accidental or not)

Comment: By what got deleted was critical, so just want to know how to back track who did this...

Comment: Don't know how you can track back the culprit. If the information was critical, I would start with a restore.

Comment: What you should not be doing is apportioning blame.  You should review your disaster recovery procedures and, if anything, talk to the person who set up the server, allowed important data to go onto it without a backup plan.  (The reason for that: mistakes will ALWAYS happen.) IMO

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless you have some form of auditing on that database or these tables, there's no way to find out who exactly did that.

If you **want** to be able to know who did it, then implement DML triggers to send auditing data to audit tables.